# Is there a way in Eclipse to find out plugins that are not used?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am struggling with this!

While trying to install some features - eclipse keeps complaining about some dependency not met and about old version of some dependencies. The messages are rather not straigtforward.

Is there a way to clean the eclipse installation of the unused plugins? Does eclipse tell you on its own as to which features/plugins have not been used (for a while)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would be the definition of an unused plugin? All plugins that Eclipse update manager is referencing are currently in use because they were installed directly or are referenced by plugins that were installed directly.

I am not aware of anything that would actively track which features you are utilizing while using Eclipse and then report on unneeded plugins.

The error that you are running into typically happens because plugin A that you have depends on plugin X v1 and you are trying to install plugin B that requires X v2. Since both v1 and v2 of X cannot be simultaneously installed, installation of B aborts.

Here are the two most common causes of users finding themselves in this situation:

1. You haven't run "search for updates" recently, so many of your plugins are on older service levels. The plugin you are installing, however, requires a newer service level of a particular plugin. Resolve by updating your installation prior to trying to install the new plugin.
2. The plugin you are trying to install was not designed to be compatible with the major version of Eclipse that you are running. For instance, you might be running Eclipse "Galileo" 3.5 platform while the plugin you are trying to install was designed to work with Eclipse "Helios" 3.6 platform. You cannot use the update manager to move between major releases. Pay attention to what yearly release the plugin advertises support for. If it needs a newer version and you are willing to upgrade, you will need to download a new package.

Outside of that, post a new question with specific failure message you are getting along with details about your current installation and what you are trying to install. Someone here ought to be able to translate the installation failure into resolution options for you.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. Not a direct answer but atleast gave me enough hints to proceed.